# Usernames with .bat/.exe in the URL - alternative

Tags: rest, security, url, get, rest-security

I am working with a URL which takes in the username for a GET call. Ex: https://example.com/details/< username >

However, if the username contains ".bat" or ".exe" (ex: mm.baty -  https://example.com/details/mm.baty), there might be some security issues.

What are some suggestions for sending the username through the URL, without compromising the security issues.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are the security issues that you are worried about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using query parameters (say `/?username=userone`), anyone can modify the value and enter some malicious values as parameter.

You can implement a regex pattern that checks the params for potentially malicious values, and deal with the response accordingly.